# Animate a dialog fragment on dismiss

Tags: android, animation

I'm trying to get a dialogfragment to animate when closed - I've tried to overwrite the dismiss, onDismiss, onCancel and onDestroy methods as below, with no luck - can someone point me in the right direction?

```
@Override
public void dismiss() {
    if (mDismissAnimationFinished) {
        super.dismiss();
    } else {

        mShrink.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                mDismissAnimationFinished = true;
                dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
        mCurrentContainer.startAnimation(mShrink);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the issue that the those dimiss/cancel functions are not being called at all or that the animation is not being run?  Also onAnimationEnd you are recalling dismiss().  Did you recently watch the movie inception ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did this with a regular dialog subclass and my solution should transfer over to `DialogFragment` exactly.

It looks like you're very close, just that you should be calling `super.dismiss()` in onAnimationEnd() rather than `dismiss()`. The reason is that if you call `dismiss()`, it will recursively call the function you are already in!

EDIT:

Define a wrapper method in the outer class or call it with YourDialogFragment.super().

```
void parentDismiss() { super.dismiss() }
```

and call that from your `onAnimationEnd()`.

Even then, you'll still have one more problem with race conditions when you are cancelling the dialog and it is being dismissed by another thread. To solve this, set a boolean `mIsDismissed` the first time your onDismiss() is called so that if it is called again before another `onStart()` occurs (you will override onStart() to flip the boolean back) that `onDismiss()`'s body isn't executed twice.

I have written a solution here, which does not use `DialogFragment`, just a regular Dialog. It is tested and working, so just look at the logic I use and copy it, or if you want, use it.

https://github.com/tom-dignan/nifty/blob/master/src/com/tomdignan/nifty/dialogs/NiftyProgressDialog.java

Comment: I think you can still call YourDialogFragment.super in your anonymous class.

Comment: @HelinWang  Yeah, that's definitely right. I wrote this a long time ago. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the outer class where the listener sits in simply by calling the class with its super. Like this: `Classname.super.method()`

```
public void dismiss() {

    yourAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            classNameOfYourDialog.super.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
    });
}
```